# How to use TypeOrm in a database already in production?

Tags: typeorm, production, node.js-typeorm

we have a platform already in production with a MySQL database, our goal is to create another platform consuming the same database...

Is it possible to use TypeOrm on a database already in production?

Comment: TypeORM works when the database uses primary keys. it can also establish a connection to that database if the specified model in your code has primary keys and matches database constraints and foreign key definitions. otherwise you either have to run migrations on the database or change your code.

Comment: you can also establish the connection without specifying the entity models, but have to execute raw queries which is not a good idea.

Comment: @AhmadDeel i have done some tests and i'm having trouble getting this to happen every time on startup it tries to run the migration.

Comment: this is because your `@Entity` model is different from what is implemented in the database. Check all models' columns and column names, constraints, primary keys, relations, etc.

Comment: first try to just add connection to your db and run a simple `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TableName` without adding models to your code. in this way you do not need migrations.

Comment: I left `@Entity` equal to the database and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you means by using TypeOrm on a database already in production!

If you mean doing some queries to the database itself, so yes you can do that.

But in principle you can have 100 platforms linking to the same database, there is no problem.

Comment: Currently we have a stock system made with laravel. We need to create an api consuming the database of this system, my question is how I can use TypeOrm without it running migrations at the beginning.